# Nvidia Digits import error no module name compt

Tags: python, nvidia-digits

New with Deep learning Frame work. trying on with Nvidia Digits and encounter problems when running Digit-denserver. 
Installation of digits i follow the link: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/master/docs/BuildDigits.md

Installation was success how ever meet a problem when running digits.
[error code fail to find module compt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVVrg.png)

Any suggestion ?
system info
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Cuda 8.0
Cudnn 5.0

Comment: Solve the problem by installing the module with pip

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem by installing the missing module with pip install.
it quite a pain to install one by one.
hope others can provide a better answer for it.